# control to the next statement after if(fork()==0) in the below program

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork, posix

I am trying to figure out where will be the control after if(fork()==0)
in the below program
Control to the next statement of if(fork()==0) is what?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
void forkexample() 
{
    // child process because return value zero
    if (fork()==0)
        printf("Hello from Child!\n");

    // parent process because return value non-zero.
    else    
        printf("Hello from Parent!\n"); 
}
int main()
{ 
    forkexample();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes............  either.......both.

Comment: I cannot understand what are you saying

Comment: Do you understand what fork() does?

Comment: Yes ..........I ..............know

Comment: OK , then you have your answer:)

Comment: The big problem is your question: 'where will be the control' when there will be two, independent flows of control on two different threads, quite possibly running on two different cores. What exactly happens 'next' is not dependent on your code.

Comment: @santhoshkumar It would help if you told us what you understand so far, and what you're still unclear on.  Say "I understand that X, but I don't understand Y".  Or, "I'm not sure whether it's X, or Y".  Or, "I think it's X.  Is that correct?"  Or, "I understand X, but that doesn't seem to tell the whole story."  Or, "I understand X, but then it gets fuzzy for me after that."

Answer (score 2):

Fork creates another process(called child process) and runs both programs simultaneously. Like Jean wrote, returns 0 in the child process and !=0 in the parent process.

The 2 processes then run separately with their own data,**control flow** etc. At that point it could go either way(child first then parent or vice versa).

ps: I would've made a comment but i can't.

Comment: Apart from the fact that you are answering a bad question, you are answering a question correctly, so I'm upvoting it. Whether you keep the upvote, or lose it if the question is deleted, is another matter:)

Answer (score 0):

Returning from fork the controls are at the point of the original call with returned value 0 in the child and !=0 in the parent. Then both processes have their own independent life. One will take the if branch the other the else. That's all.